# Tab Index stops working after selecting value from DropDownList in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, user-interface, webforms

Im working on an ASP.Net web forms application, where I have a form and the Index is working correctly, until I select a value from one specific control, a dropdownlist. After that no matter what control I am on if I press TAB it will go to the URL/Address Bar, from there to the search bar and then again to the URL bar...

Has anybody has something like this happen to them?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the tab moves back and forth between addr bar and search bar, and it never goes to page again? I've never faced this issue but my guess would be that your DDL is in UpdatePanel and also with AutoPostBack true. In which case it might be happening that the once you change the value, the DDL and other controls are getting rendered again. This will lose the focused control (the old DDL) and hence the browser is taking focus to addr bar. Just a guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm I solved it.. well... found the cause.. it seems that in a part of the code after changing DropDownList it fired a "loading" dialog from ComponentArt, which apparently is not working, the dialog is not visible but it IS screwing up the tab order, took it away and its working now....